# List of <String> Loop short

Tags: vb.net

this is my New List (Of String)

```
    Dim NChooseKListX1, NChooseKListX2, NChooseKListX3, NChooseKListX4, NChooseKListX5, NChooseKListX6, NChooseKListX7, NChooseKListX8,
    NChooseKListX9, NChooseKListX10, NChooseKListX11 As New List(Of String)()
```

Code: How can I make NChooseKListX after X be its value (PositionalNCKX) like NChooseKListX (PositionalNCX) without writing the value so many times.

```
  If strNCKXDigit(PositionalNCKX - 1) = strNCKXDigitA(0) Then
                    NChooseKListX (the value must be changed according to PositionalNCKX) .Add(NChooseKLTxt.Lines(RWNCKlines))
                ElseIf strNCKXDigit(PositionalNCKX - 1) = strNCKXDigitA(1) Then
                    NChooseKListX (the value must be changed according to PositionalNCKX).Add(NChooseKLTxt.Lines(RWNCKlines))
     End If
```

Comment: This is not ONE list, this is a bunch of list(Of String). If you wanted to initialize one list with those values, this is how: `Dim list As New List(Of String)({"a", "b", "c"})`

Comment: Hard to decode, but surely you want to create an array of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you have variable names that are different only by a number and you wish you could somehow get VB to let you use some changing number to access the differnet variable names, you have.. an array!

Or a collection, but let's do this with an array:

```
   Dim NChooseKListX(10) As List(Of String)

   
   'see how now we access them by index integer. 
   'This loop initializes the array slots so they are all new lists
   'It is necessary otherwise NChooseKListX(...) will be Nothing,
   'so don't throw this loop away thinking it's just a demo; you need it
   For i = 0 to 10 
 
     NChooseKListX(i) = New List(Of String)

   Next i
```

Remember that arrays are zero based in .net so the first one you called NChooseKListX1 is `NChooseKListX(0)`, all the way up to `NChooseKListX(10)` (your NChooseKListX11)

Now you can address these lists by some integer variable like `PositionalNCKX` but remember it has to range between 0 and 10 so you might need to minus some number off it